# Should I explicily add/delete OpenGraph objects that are added to / removed from my site?

Tags: facebook-graph-api, facebook-like, rendering, facebook-opengraph

Some OpenGraph newbie-isms:

Suppose I put up a page on my site that is properly marked with OpenGraph metatags to indicate that it represents a OG "video" object.  This is a straightforward implementation of the OG Video spec; no custom stuff is involved.  Two questions:

- Should I do some sort of POST to Facebook to tell it that the page/object exists, or do I just wait for a user to hit the Like button or do some sort of other Facebook-y action on the page (which, as it seems, will lead Facebook to scrape the page and do whatever it does with it)?
- If the page is removed from my site, should I then do some sort of POST to tell Facebook that the page has gone away?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There is no need to explicitly tell Facebook about the existence of an Open Graph Page. When someone clicks the like button for the first time (or shares the link on Facebook by some other way) the Facebook servers query the URL to read the OG Tags so it knows what the Newsfeed story should look like.

Similarly there is no need to inform Facebook that the OG Page has gone away. That being said it is better to just allow your OG pages to continue to exist if possible to ensure they continue to drive traffic to your website.